# How to define an R function for it to be called in the caller's environment

Tags: r, function

As an R user coming from Python, I am confused by this code not working:

```
library(glue)
glue2 <- function(str) glue(glue(str))

do <- function() {
    x <- 1
    glue("{x}")
    y <- 1
    glue2("{{y}}")
}
do()
```

`Rscript` outputs:

```
Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'y' not found
Calls: do ... glue_data -> <Anonymous> -> .transformer -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

What is different between `glue` and `glue2` that `glue` is able to access `x`, but `glue2` is not able to access `y`? How can I redefine `glue2` to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use `.envir = parent.frame()`, see here:

> One important consideration when doing this is to include `.envir = parent.frame()` in the wrapper to ensure the evaluation environment is correct.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glue/vignettes/transformers.html

For me, this is working:

```
library(glue)
glue2 <- function(str) {
    str <- glue(str, .envir = parent.frame())
    str <- glue(str, .envir = parent.frame())
    return(str)
}

do <- function() {
    x <- "y"
    y <- 1
    message(glue2("{{{x}}}"))
}
do()
```

Answer (score 1):

`glue` looks for an object present in it's current environment. If it is not found it looks for it in the global environment. Since `y` variable is present in the function `do` but it is not available in function `glue2` it returns you the error. It will work if you define `y` in global environment.

```
library(glue)

y <- 10
glue2 <- function(str) glue(glue(str))

do <- function() {
  x <- 1
  glue("{x}")
  y <- 1
  glue2("{y}")
}
do()
#10
```

Or pass the value to the function :

```
y <- 10
glue2 <- function(str, y) glue(glue(str))

do <- function() {
  x <- 1
  glue("{x}")
  y <- 1
  glue2("{y}", y)
}
do()
#1
```

Comment: All of this is true, but does not explain why it is working with `glue`.

Comment: It does explain. Because the value `x` is present in the same environment as the `glue` function is called, hence it works for it.